# I'm populating a form using PHP, how do I make the select list sticky?

Tags: php

I am using the code below to populate a select list from fields in a db and it works great, the problem is how do I make it sticky? if the user types in the wrong info the page reloads and it does not remember what was selected from the list.

I have tried a few different if statements but i couldn't get it working. The list populates with 15 customer names, what would be the best way to tackle this? Thanks

```
<fieldset>
        <legend><b>Check to see how many times a user has logged in</b></legend>
        <p><label for="fname">First Name:</label><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php if (!empty($fname)) echo $fname; ?>" /></p>
      <p><label for="lname">Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="<?php if (!empty($lname)) echo $lname; ?>" /></p>
      <p><label for="customer">Customers:</label>
          <select name="customer">
                <?php
                    $custNames = getCustomers();
                    foreach($custNames as $customers){
                        echo '<option value="' . $customers . '">' . $customers . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
      <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="See Logins" name="submit" /></p>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `if` statement which prints a `selected` attribute to the chosen  element.

For example:

```
<?php
$custNames = getCustomers();
foreach($custNames as $customers){
  $extra = '';
  if($_POST['customer'] == $customers) {
    $extra = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  echo '<option value="' . $customers . '" ' . $extra . '>' . $customers . '</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I like the idea of using the extra but how could i test against the 15 customers to see which one was selected to make it stick? Thanks

Comment: I just showed you how. Read the posted form data and compare it with each value in your loop.

Comment: I dont know how i didnt see the answer to my question, thanks. That did it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: again, sorry for the stupid question, i must have glossed right the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp) or store that information as [session](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_sessions.asp) data.
And then use the code posted by *Emil Vikström* above.

Comment: Such data is relevant only after the page has been posted. Conveniently the data is already within the _POST array, so I don't see the point in storing the data in the session (and definitely in cookies (cookies aren't a dumping place for miscellaneous data!)) other than if the user navigates away from the form.